# Dispatchs fire together inside UseEffect with Async function

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk, use-context, use-reducer

There is a Profile component that creates a 3D face using an async function. To inform the user to wait, two dispatches is fired before and after the heavy task inside the **UseEffect**. The problem is both of these dispatched only fire after the heavy task is done.

Profile.js

```
const Profile = (props) => {
  const [face3D, setFace3D] = useState(null)
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext)

  const drawFace = async () => {
    // a heavy calculation
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // show user loading
    dispatch({
      type: "USER_LOADING",
      payload: true
    })

    drawFace().then( face => {
      setFace3D(face)

      // clear user loading
      dispatch({
        type: "USER_LOADING",
        payload: false
      })
    })

  }, [props.data])

  return (
    <Canvas>
      { face3D }
    </Canvas>
  )
}

 export default Profile
```

UserContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import { createReducer } from 'react-use'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export const UserContext = createContext()
const useThunkReducer = createReducer(thunk, logger);

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
const initialState = {
  loading: false
}

const [state, dispatch] = useThunkReducer(UserReducer, initialState)

return (
  <UserContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
    { props.children }
  </UserContext.Provider>
)
}

export default UserContextProvider
```

PS: **redux-logger** shows a correct sequence of dispatching, even logging the reducer shows changing the state to *true* and finally to *false* but the state only reflects the last dispatch (a situation similar to mutating the state, but it is not mutated)

Answer (score 0):

Use finally block and then add loading false dispatch inside that block.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've noted that `drawFace` is a "heavy calculation", I suspect that it is not actually asynchronous. What I think is happening is:

1. The first `dispatch` is called
2. drawFace is executed and calculates its return value. Because the function is `async`, the result is wrapped in a promise.
3. `.then()` adds a task to the event loop that makes the call to `setFace3D` and the second call to `dispatch`.

Try calling drawFace after a timeout:

```
dispatch(...)

setTimeout(() => {
  drawFace().then(face => {
    setFace3D(face);
    dispatch(...)
  })
}, 0)
```

Marking a function with `async` doesn't automatically run the function body on a background thread or anything like that. Instead, it does two things:

- Allows the `await` keyword to be used
- Automatically wraps the returned value (or a thrown error) in a promise.

Notice that in the following example, "calculate" is logged before "after calling calculate", even though the function is marked `async`.

```
async function calculate() {
  console.log("calculate")
}

console.log("before calling calculate")
calculate().then(() => { 
  console.log("calculation done")
})
console.log("after calling calculate")

// Result:
// "before calling calculate"
// "calculate"
// "after calling calculate"
// "calculation done"
```

Comment: Thanks. I used a `setTimeout` but did not work. Only the change in the state became a function of the delay time. I also removed the `async` and executed it as a normal function. No improvement! Will try using `await`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @stephen-jennings explanation, `async` function is removed and the code changed as below:

```
const Profile = (props) => {

  const [face3D, setFace3D] = useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext)

  const drawFace = () => {
    // a heavy calculation
    // setFace3D( face )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    
    dispatch({
      type: "USER_LOADING",
      payload: isLoading
    })
    setIsLoading(false)

  }, [face3D])


  useEffect(() => {
    const delay = setTimeout(() => {
      drawFace()
    }, 0)
  }, [props.data])

  return (
    <Canvas>
      { face3D }
    </Canvas>
  )
}

export default Profile
```